# CPU frequency stuck at 1.550 GHz

Tags: release-juno, system, amd, cpu

I have my system running Juno with the 5.3.11 Kernel, with a Ryzen 7 1700 set in the UEFI to 3.9 GHz, but I've noticed the cpu doesn't go above 1.550 GHz, even while rendering with Blender.
Entering

```
watch -n1 "lscpu | grep 'MHz' | awk '{print $1}'"
```

In the terminal gives me something like this

```
CPU MHz:             1374.089
CPU max MHz:         3900,0000
CPU min MHz:         1550,0000
```

The CPU frequency goes below the minimum and never above it.
Some animations have also been sluggish, so this issue might explain that.
How can I fix this?

Here are the results for `lscpu`

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               1
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core Processor
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             1356.654
CPU max MHz:         3900,0000
CPU min MHz:         1550,0000
BogoMIPS:            7784.61
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

And `lsmod | grep amd`

```
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
kvm                   651264  1 kvm_amd
ccp                    94208  1 kvm_amd
amdgpu               4194304  13
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 amdgpu
drm                   491520  7 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 igb,amdgpu
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt
```

Comment: Do you have a laptop? Check the temperatures and cpu governor.

Comment: No I'm on my desktop, temps should be totally fine as they've always been on my Windows install. How to check the cpu governor?

Comment: Okay I managed to check the cpu governor, I also set it to 'performance', but nothing changes this comes up for all the cores when using "cpufreq-info"
"hardware limits: 1.55 GHz - 3.90 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.90 GHz, 1.55 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
current policy: frequency should be within 1.55 GHz and 1.55 GHz.
The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use within this range."
Sooo how do I change the policy?

Comment: Don't assume the temperatures are fine. Since a wrong driver or governor could be throttling your cpu. Or it could be the fan that's not working correctly.
I don't know exactly how to solve your problem but you can try some things if you want: install `lm-sensors fancontrol ` and execute `sensors-detect`. You can use fancontrol to make sure the fan is working as expected.  You can also install the Hardware Enablement Stack to update some drivers.`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` .

Comment: I see you upgraded your kernel manually but maybe you should try with the HWE kernel instead. You could also install `amd64-microcode` (proprietary) to receive bugfixes from amd.

By the way, it's strange that you only have 2 frecuency steps. It looks like you are using a wrong driver or maybe you set something weird in the UEFI configuration. Can you update your question with the output of `lscpu` and `lsmod | grep amd` so that we know what drivers you are using?

Comment: It is indeed weird that there are only 2 frequency steps... Perhaps a wrong driver, I don't really know, I'm also not sure how to install the HWE kernel. I'm still kind of a beginner to linux so I don't know all the install stuff and such.
I don't think my UEFI is the problem as I've been running this config for a long time on my Windows install without any issues.
My temps are good, like 1.55 GHz good... While running Blender at full load the temps remain in the mid 30's...
I updated some drivers with the command you gave and I'll update the post after a reboot.

Comment: Well... I updated the drivers and now the system won't boot... screen remains black with only a blinking dash in the top left...

Comment: On grub you can press e and write `nomodeset` in between `quiet splash`. That should let you boot. You can then remove the driver that caused the issue.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: Okay after runnning ```amdgpu-pro-uninstall``` I got the system running again. Now to fix the real issue!

Comment: I added the requested outputs, I think I'm still running kernel 5.3 and not HWE

Comment: To install the graphics driver try with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to make sure you use the correct one for your system. Regarding the kernel you should be able to choose it from grub at boot. It may be under advanced options for elementary.

Comment: HWE is not in the grub menu, 5.3.11 is the highest, which I am running now

Comment: It should be kernel version 4.X.something. it doesn't say hwe.

Comment: So I shouldn't run 5.3 right now?